# How to setup cscope with aquamacs on MacOS?

Tags: macos, emacs, cscope, aquamacs

Can you please tell me how can I setup cscope with aquamacs on MacOS?

I have followed a link from Google saying how to build a cscope database for my source code. But how can I invoke cscope with aquamacs?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

M-x shell then 'cd your_dir; cscope ...." ?

Answer (score 0):

Install xscope.el http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CScopeAndEmacs#toc3

I use the GNU Cocoa build of Emacs, but I think this will work for you too.

Answer (score 0):

The following was performed using Aquamacs 2.3a [GNU Emacs 23.3.50.1 (i386-apple-darwin9.8.0, NS apple-appkit-949.54) of 2011-08-04 on braeburn.aquamacs.org - Aquamacs Distribution 2.3a] on Mac OS X 10.6.8:

Download cscope from http://sourceforge.net/projects/cscope/files/ (Version used 15.7a). bunzip2 and untar the software. Execute 'configure'; Do 'make'. If you find an error, check the following page and patch the file constant.h as described in instructions at http://cean2wizard.blogspot.com/2011/02/cscope-157a-build-with-mac-os-x-snow.html. Basically, set TERMINFO to be 1 for Mac. Do 'make' and then 'sudo make install'.

Go to the contrib directory. Copy xcscope.el into ~/Library/Application\ Support/Aquamacs\ Emacs/

Change directory to ~/Library/Application\ Support/Aquamacs\ Emacs/, and edit site-start.el and add the line:

(require `xcscope)

Start Aquamacs.